# error JSONException java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, sql, json

I am trying to code android studio which that program get the data from SQLserver and the JSON I parse that into IIS and access with JSON Service. but, when I opened the program, the error shown at the program is `org.json.JSONException:Value java.net.UnknownHostException of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`

I am using recycleview for refresh the data and here is my code in android studio. this is my Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
// CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
private RecyclerView recyler_view;
private DataAdapter MyAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Make call to AsyncTask
    new AsyncFetch().execute();
}

private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            // Enter URL address where your json file resides
            // Even you can make call to php file which returns json data
            url = new URL("http://11misd17c0001/JSONWebAPI/Handler1.ashx");       // <- link JSON nantinya

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {

            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return (result.toString());

            } else {

                return ("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //this method will be running on UI thread

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        List<NewData> data=new ArrayList<>();

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        try {

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                NewData datanew = new NewData();
                datanew.DocumentNo= json_data.getString("doc_no");
                datanew.EmployeeNo= json_data.getString("emp_no");
                datanew.DocumentDate= json_data.getString("doc_date");
                data.add(datanew);
            }

            // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
            recyler_view = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyler_view);
            MyAdapter = new DataAdapter(MainActivity.this, data);
            recyler_view.setAdapter(MyAdapter);
            recyler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}}
```

this is my code for DataAdapter class

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<NewData> data= Collections.emptyList();
NewData current;
int currentPos=0;

// create constructor to innitilize context and data sent from MainActivity
public DataAdapter(Context context, List<NewData> data){
    this.context=context;
    inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data=data;
}

// Inflate the layout when viewholder created
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.display_data, parent,false);
    MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

// Bind data
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    // Get current position of item in recyclerview to bind data and assign values from list
    MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
    NewData current=data.get(position);
    myHolder.txtdoc.setText(current.DocumentNo);
    myHolder.txtdate.setText(current.EmployeeNo);
    myHolder.txtno.setText(current.DocumentDate);

}

// return total item from List
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}


class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView txtdoc;
    TextView txtdate;
    TextView txtno;

    // create constructor to get widget reference
    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtdoc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtdoc);
        txtdate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtdate);
        txtno = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtno);
    }

}}
```

and this is my code for NewData(constructor)

```
public class NewData {

public String DocumentNo;
public String EmployeeNo;
public String DocumentDate;}
```

thanks for your help..

Comment: Im going to guess here but it looks like Android cannot talk to host: `http://11misd17c0001`. Its going to be a networking issue, and one that you will need to handle (i.e., try printing out the value of result in `onPostExecute`; my guess is that it looks nothing like a JSONArray)... The message will be coming from `return e.toString();`

Comment: when i access `http://11misd17c0001` from IIS, it can access and shown JSON Service.. and for the return where must i put that? @GavinHarris

Comment: That server is it on your network or is it your local host? Check IOException as this will give you some hints. FYI: With Android Emulator you need to treat it like a Virtual Machine (i.e., it has its own access to the network) and so it cannot access resources on your PC without correct configuration of those resources (i.e., exposure to the network)

Comment: i hosting that to IIS so everyone can access that JSON if they have same network with me.. and for the emulator.. if i open that in my pc can i access that? @GavinHarris

Comment: You could try it from the Browser on the Emulator? That is the issue though (drop a breakpoint at the IOException, or a `log.e("MyApp", e.getMessage());`

Comment: no.. i compile my android studio program in my emulator and it installed like an application

Comment: post your JSON Data